# What is the best concurrency way of doing 10 000 continuous opencv operations simultaneously in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, file-io, concurrency

I used to have a relatively simple Python3 app that read a video streaming source and did continuous opencv and I/O-heavy (with files and databases) operations:

```
cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(stream_url)
while True:
    # ...
    # openCV operations
    # database I/O operations
    # file I/O operations
    # ...
```

The app ran smoothly. However, there arose a need to do this not just with 1 channel, but with many, potentially 10 000 channels. Now, let's say I have a list of these channels (stream_urls). If I wrap my usual code inside `for stream_url in stream_urls:`, it will of course not work, because the iteration will never proceed further than the 0th index. So, the first thing that comes to mind is concurrency.

Now, as much as I know, there are 3 ways of doing concurrent programming in Python3: **threading**, **asyncio**, and **multiprocessing**:

- I understand that in the case of **multiprocessing** the OS creates new (instances of) Python interpreter so there can be at most as many instances as there are cores of the machine, which seldom exceeds 16; however, the number of processes can be potentially up to 10 000. Also, the overhead from the use of multiprocessing exceeds the performance gains if the number of processes are more than a certain amount, so this one appears to be useless.
- The case of **threading** seems the easiest in terms of the machinery it uses. I'd just wrap my code in a function and create threads like the following:

```
from threading import Thread

def work_channel(ch_src):
    cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(ch_src)
    while True:
        # ...
        # openCV operations
        # database I/O operations
        # file I/O operations
        # ...

for stream_url in stream_urls:
    Thread(target=work_channel, args=(stream_url,), daemon=True).start()
```

But there are a few problems with threading: first, using more than 11-17 threads nullifies any of its favourable effects because of the overhead costs. Also, **it's not safe to work with file I/O in threading**, which is a very important concern for me.

- I don't know how to use **asyncio** and couldn't find how to do what I want with it.

Given the above scenario, which one of the 3 (or more if there are other methods that I am unaware of) concurrency methods should I use for the fastest, most accurate (or at least expected) performance? And what way should I use that method correctly?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @nathancy Nathan, thanks for your valuable comment. Bur the method you pointed out to me is for working with one channel (namely, `src`). What do you think the best way is to work with many channels?

Comment: You can create multiple stream objects and pass in a different `src` channel into each object. In my setup, I use that widget to stream 4 different IP cameras. So if you want to work with multiple channels, you can pass in a different `src` into each one. Since the reading/processing in contained within the class, each channel will have its own dedicated thread

Comment: @nathancy Are you sure it's going to work with, for example, 400 channels?

Comment: I'm not completely sure if its going to work with that many channels but I have gotten it to work with around 10 (I have never tried anything more than that)

Comment: @nathancy That's exactly my point and I've mentioned that in my question too. Also, I do quite a lot of DB and file I/O operations within each loop and using threading might corrupt these operations. While I suspect `asyncio` is the way to go, I can't find how to use it for my goal.

Comment: Theoretically it should work since each channel is its own object so you are limited by the computing power of your system

Answer (score 0):

Spawning more threads than your computer has cores is very much possible.

Could be as simple as:

```
import threading

all_urls = [your url list]

def threadfunction(url):
    cap_vid = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
    while True:
        # ...
        # openCV operations
        # file I/O operations
        # ...

for stream_url in all_urls:
    threading.Thread(target=threadfunction, args=(stream_url,)).start()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mate. But can you please elaborate on what possible constraints I would have if I use this method? And can you please let me know if there are better (faster, more accurate) ways than this one or is this indeed my best bet? Also, notice that I said the number of max parallel jobs ~ the number of cores about multiprocessing, not threading (which you mentioned).